# How to grep a text in a file with new/breaks line

Tags: grep, newline, break

I have to parse the content of multiple files with this content:

```
style=3D""><a href=3D"https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=
K/bWFyY29A1234529zYW50dWNjaS5ldQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse&amp;ndid=3DHMTU1Mjk=
wODY5OTA1MDk2NTptYXJjb0BtYXJjb3NhbnR1Y2NpLmV1Ojg1OQ" style=3D"color:#3b599
```

I have to extract the https link, but my grep command can't ignore the new line return, and end with a trunk result:

COMMAND

```
grep -r -m1 -oh "https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email*\s*[^ ]*" /folder/
```

RESULT

```
https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=
```

DESIDERED RESULT

```
https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=K/bWFyY29A1234529zYW50dWNjaS5ldQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse&amp;ndid=3DHMTU1MjkwODY5OTA1MDk2NTptYXJjb0BtYXJjb3NhbnR1Y2NpLmV1Ojg1OQ
```

PS: '=' character is not (always) part of link, but it is the format of the file when break the line.

NB: `https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/` is the only constant of the link repeated in all files.

IF I add -z option, -m1 option is ignored and the result is:

```
https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=
K/bWFyY29A1234529zYW50dWNjaS5ldQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse&amp;ndid=3DHMTU1Mjk=
wODY5OTA1MDk2NTptYXJjb0BtYXJjb3NhbnR1Y2NpLmV1Ojg1OQ"https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=
K/bWFyY29A1234529zYW50dWNjaS5ldQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse&amp;ndid=3DHMTU1Mjk=
wODY5OTA1MDk2NTptYXJjb0BtYXJjb3NhbnR1Y2NpLmV1Ojg1OQ"https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=
K/bWFyY29A1234529zYW50dWNjaS5ldQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse&amp;ndid=3DHMTU1Mjk=
wODY5OTA1MDk2NTptYXJjb0BtYXJjb3NhbnR1Y2NpLmV1Ojg1OQ"
```

IF I add |head -3 after the command seem to work BUT http is repeated in the last line

COMMAND

```
grep -r -oh -z "https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email*\s*[^ ]*" /folder/ |head-3

https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=
K/bWFyY29A1234529zYW50dWNjaS5ldQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse&amp;ndid=3DHMTU1Mjk=
wODY5OTA1MDk2NTptYXJjb0BtYXJjb3NhbnR1Y2NpLmV1Ojg1OQ"https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=
```

How can I exclude it?

Answer (score 1):

`man grep`:

```
-z, --null-data
       Treat  the  input  as  a set of lines, each terminated by a zero
       byte (the ASCII NUL character) instead of a newline. - -
```

So:

```
$ grep -z -r -m1 -oh "https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email*\s*[^ ]*" file
```

Output:

```
https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email/19AbCDx=
K/bWFyY29A1234529zYW50dWNjaS5ldQ/?app_redirect=3DFalse&amp;ndid=3DHMTU1Mjk=
wODY5OTA1MDk2NTptYXJjb0BtYXJjb3NhbnR1Y2NpLmV1Ojg1OQ"
```

The newlines will still be there but you could delete them with `tr -d \\n`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now the -m1 option doesn't work. I have as result all the http links repeated into the file... Why?

Comment: The `-m1` is working just fine, it's your regexp that's bad. With `https...[^ ]*` you're asking grep to match from `https...` to the end of the file since there are no blank chars in the file for `[^ ]*` to stop at and so grep is cheerfully doing exactly that. Try changing `"https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email*\s*[^ ]*"` to `'https://123456789.com/accounts/confirm_email[^"]*'`.